# How to change screen orientation in Windows when running as service (C++ code)?

Tags: c++, windows

I know how to control the screen from code (C++) when i run as desktop app. i see that when i try it in service i wrote, i cant control the screen since service cant see the attached display.
I tried to use function from user32.dll and also tried using WinUser.h:

```
DEVMODE devmode;
ZeroMemory(&devmode, sizeof(DEVMODE));
devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);
//first get setting for "current" screen
if(!EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &devmode))
   return STATUS_ERROR;

if (devmode.dmFields | DM_DISPLAYORIENTATION)
{
    devmode.dmDisplayOrientation = orientation;
    LONG r = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, 0);
}
```

Comment: What screen are you trying to control when you don't have a display?

Comment: I have a display. the issue is my code is running as service and it cant access the attached disaply

Comment: A service runs in an isolated session, session 0.  While it has a window station and a (minimal) desktop, that desktop cannot be attached to a monitor.  That's would be a pretty gross bug that invites shatter attacks.  So sure, this does not work, it is not supposed to work.  You'll have to instead uses a normal process that runs in the user's desktop.  You can get it automatically started when the user logs in.  Use WTSRegisterSessionNotifcationEx() to get notifications about a session switch, tells you when you should stop tinkering with the monitor.